# RX/TX led colors

Tags: led, serial

I'll place leds on RX/TX to monitor activity.

Do you know if there's a kind of convention for the colors of theses ?

I've take a look on google but have found nothing.

(For now RX Red, TX Green, just to remember myself **R** ed-> **R** x)

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any standard or convention for RX/TX indicator colors specifically. Some boards seem to also use yellow, blue or amber, besides red and green. If it is of any relevance, it is worth noting that the human eye is most sensitive to green, so it might make sense to use green for whichever direction will have shorter bursts of bits going through - that way, the longer bursts would be red or yellow or whatever, and both colors would be perceived well enough.

Comment: As said in Nick Alexeev, red is mostly used to indicate a fault, so try to avoid it for traffic. If you can mount SMD leds on both side, you can use one side for RX and the other one for TX with green leds.

Comment: Placing LED's "on" Tx/Rx lines is generally not a good idea, loading data transmission lines can throw things out of spec and introduce performance issues. Wiring an LED to an indicator pin on a device (EG a GPIO pin on a micro that goes high when transmission is happening) is a better idea.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a CE guideline for indicator colors:

**Red** - fault, alarm.
**Yellow** - warning, attention.  (The are a some specific exceptions: "cut" indicator on RF generators is always yellow.)
**Blue** - working, energized, treatment in progress.  (In my experience, blue LEDs catch the eye and look cool, but can be distracting sometimes.)
**Green** - everything else.

Serial TX and RX should be both green, or both blue, or one of each.

Comment: I doubt this applies to data link/traffic indicators. Ethernet typically has green for link and yellow for traffic. Bluetooth has blue. Wifi cards vary (red, green, blue, white, etc).

Comment: I've been using red for TX and Blue/Green for Rx for ages now. Whoops?

Comment: @ConnorWolf  If it were a medical device, and the LEDs are for the operator consumption, that could be a whoops.  For other more benign devices - may be you can get away with it.

Comment: If power is in short supply or running on a battery I use red because the high efficiency Red LED's use the least current / power. I built a RS232 signal indicator tool that consisted of 4 LED's connected to the signal lines and 0V when trying to establish RS232 communications between various equipment became a chore.

Comment: @NickAlexeev - If the CE guideline you're citing is specifically for **medical devices**, you should mention that. Right now, it sounds like you're claiming it's a *general* guideline, rather then an application-specific one.

Comment: @ConnorWolf   This is a general guideline, afaik.  [I can't seem to find a reference, though.]  It's more strictly enforced in medical devices.  I've first encountered this guideline, when working on an medical RF generator design.

Comment: Maybe it was IEC 60073 (Basic and safety principles for man-machine interface, marking and identification, Coding principles for indicators and actuators). Section 4.2.1 (Coding by colours) is about the recommended colors of visual indicators. Red = Danger, Emergency, Fault; Amber = Warning, Abnormal state; Green = Safe state, Normal state; Blue = Mandatory attention required; White = Anything.

Answer (score 1):

I think the machine safety regulations inside the EU area says: avoid the red and the green signal colors. Reason for that is the color blindness.
Tx and Rx color is flavor question.