# Red for hot, blue for cold - or vice versa?

Tags: standard, indicator

Just wondering if there is any standard way of using LED colors to represent temperature. I have a board connected to a Peltier. When the active side (not heat sink side) is heating, I turn on a red LED. When cooling, a blue LED. Mnemonic - red hot, ice blue.

Technically however, blue is the hotter part of the spectrum. Does anyone use or specify what colors to use for these function indicators?

Comment: This might be a better question for UX.SE

Comment: In shower this msy be matter of life and death

Comment: I doubt more people know about spectrum temperature than those using water taps and thermostats every day of their lives.

Comment: [This](https://www.google.fr/search?tbm=isch&q=warm+cold+colors) is what everybody learns in school.

Comment: Even in the case of visible light, higher colour temperatures (bluer) are typically called 'cool white', vs lower temperature light being called 'warm white'. I do not think you will find any example where blue is hot and red is cold.

Comment: Please use labeled indicators, there are colorblind people.

Comment: If you are designing a medical device, then nothing should light up red except in a life-threatening emergency. If you are designing HVAC equipment for the U.S.A. market then read=heating, blue=cooling is standard.

Answer (score 3):

There is apparently a Euro standard (EN60204-1) for indicators that claims red and yellow for warning purposes.

Blue seems intuitive to me for cooling. If you want to reserve red, there are very, very nice neon orange LEDs available. Red and blue are commonly used for hot/cold faucets (and much more reliable than the English H/C (Hot/Cold) which is C/F (Chaud/Froid) in French and can lead to getting scalded- ask me how I know)

[image]

Stock photo from [here](https://www.dreamstime.com/stock-illustration-hot-cold-faucets-isolated-white-background-d-illustration-image76325975).

Comment: But have mercy on the color-blind and do include the texts! And keep to the somewhat widely accepted standard of left=hort / right=cold.

Comment: The CE standard for indicator colors doesn't seem to mesh well with the everyday hot-cold color scale.  The CE standard says that red should be used for alarm only (very fitting for overheat alarm).  More in [this earlier thread](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/95949/7036).

Comment: @NickAlexeev The ~600nm neon orange is very nice- maybe it is somewhat coherent because it speckles like laser light.

Answer (score 1):

In thermography dark colors such as blue are used to indicate cold areas whereas bright colors yellow/red are used to indicate hotter areas.

[image: Image from https://www.infratec-infrared.com]